# Obtener Id de mi usuario logueado en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Quiero extraer el id de el usuario que esté logueado en este momento. Lo único que tengo de datos del usuario es el nombre de usuario:

```
include("../bd.php");


if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
        session_start(); 
}
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
$resultados_id = mysqli_query($conectarbd, $query);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados_id);
echo $usuario;

?>
```

Esto es lo que tengo para sacar el usuario, pero no sé cómo sacar el ID del usuario.

Comment: Si la columna del id del usuario se llama `id` en la tabla, deberías encontrar el dato que buscas haciendo esto: `echo $fila['id'];` En caso de no llamarse así, cambia `id` por como se llame esa columna. Si no funciona, depura con un `var_dump($fila);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Ya me funciono graicas :) nose como hacer para ponerte estrella o algo haci gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la columna del id del usuario se llama `id` en la tabla, deberías encontrar el dato que buscas haciendo esto:
**`echo $fila['id'];`** En caso de no llamarse así, cambia `id` por como se llame esa columna. Si no funciona, depura con un `var_dump($fila);` para revisar el contenido de la consulta.

Debes trabajar sobre `$fila`, porque es allí donde estarían los datos que traiga la consulta.

Considera también usar un método más específico. `mysqli_fetch_array()` te da los mismos datos bajo dos formas de organización: con índices numéricos y con índices asociativos. Quizá convenga cambiarlo por [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), que te da los datos sólo una vez con un índice asociativo, así evitas la duplicidad:

```
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados_id);
echo $fila['id'];
#Sólo para depurar
var_dump($fila);
```

### Nota sobre la seguridad

Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Considera usar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese gravísimo riesgo.